# Throwing Exception not throws

Tags: java

I just started to learn java. I'm trying to learn how Exception Handling works so i made up a little  program:

```
public class Car {
    protected String type;
    protected String[] colors;
    protected boolean isAvaiable;

    public Car(String type, Collection<String> colors, boolean isAvaiable) throws NoColorException {
        if (colors == null || colors.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoColorException("No colours!");
        } else {
            this.type = type;
            this.colors = (String[]) colors.toArray();
            this.isAvaiable = isAvaiable;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Car n = new Car("asd", new ArrayList(), true);
        } catch (NoColorException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

This is my Exception class:

```
public class NoColorException extends Exception {
    public NoColorException(String string) {
        super(string);
    }
}
```

The above code should throw an exception when i try to create the object but instead it runs.

Why does this happening?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You catch the exception and do nothing if the exception is catched:

Change:

```
try {
    Car n = new Car("asd", new ArrayList(), true);
} catch (NoColorException ex) {

}
```

To:

```
try {
    Car n = new Car("asd", new ArrayList(), true);
} catch (NoColorException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage())
}
```

and you will see the exception.

Note: Neven Catch an exception without logging it.

Answer (score 6):

Your code throws an exception, which you catch in your empty catch block :

```
catch (NoColorException ex) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It runs clearly because you are catching the Exception thrown in your Empty catch as said by @Eran and @Jens.

In order to see the Text in Red colors ; that is to throw the exception and visualize the Exception flow, Just make this change :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoColorException {

        Car n = new Car("asd", new ArrayList(), true);
}
```

Comment: @l4mpi Why It would not compile..? It's the main() method, So compiler will only warn you of the Event

Comment: @l4mpi And No IDE will complain about it

Comment: Oops, I missed the "throws" declaration. But still, the "In order to see the Text in Red colors" part is complete nonsense and 100% dependend on the execution environment.